# Windows application using GUI and Database in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, user-interface, visual-studio-2012, mfc, windows

I have just learned C++ and I would like to make an windows application(including GUI and Database) using C++ and MFC libraries in Visual Studio 2012.

I tried doing the above by using MFC application option in VS 2012 but i was not able to do it.

Can you please give the corresponding tutorials to implement the above or suggest me the method to implement it.

I know programming only C and C++.

Thank you.

Comment: This probably is not the best place to ask people to do Googling for you. Any actual problems you encountered when trying to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Go the the MSDN site

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.aspx

and search for "MFC database tutorial". There a several of them.